SSH to Remote Server with PKI
I used to connect to a jump server using plain username and password with netmiko as shown in the example below.
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

def connect_server():
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(
        host="jump_server_hostname",
        device_type="linux",
        username="user_name",
        password="password",
    )
    return net_connect

But previously, due to security requirements this server will only support ssh using PKI usb.
How can I migrate my old script to be able to connect using this PKI?
